# Where can i find the icone view fewer attributes in android studio

Tags: android-studio

The icone doesn't show up when i select a textview for example, i dont know why ? Is it because it's the latest version. Sorry if the probleme is dump but  I'm new in android development so excuse my question !

Comment: Have you click the Attribute toolbar on the top right of Android Studio?

Comment: yes i did click on it but the the icone "view fewer attributes" does not appear, currently im watching a tutoriel about android development that uses android studio but not this version the icone appear.